# Want to keep data in AppFabric Cache intact after cluster restart

Tags: caching, appfabric, appfabric-cache

I want to keep the data in AppFabric Cache intact on Cluster restart.
It normally flushes all the data in cache. Can anyone tell me is this possible to fulfill this requirement?

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: As usual memory cache doesn't store this data, because it's Memory cache. It used for caching. If data needs to be stored across restarts, then it needs to be saved into DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any in-memory cache when restarted will flush all data. Since data is in process' memory, when process restarts all data will be lost.

However some caching solutions like [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) provide features such as [cache startup loader](http://www.alachisoft.com/support/support_articles/how-to-use-cache-startup-loader.html) which can be used to pre-populate cache at startup or after restart with configurable set of data. E.g. you can easily maintain a list of keys on each node (using a write-behind provider etc) and at server restart populate cache with that set of keys and data using startup loader.

Unfortunately cache startup loader feature is not available in Appfabric cache.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not currently supported inside the AppFabric however there are other cache providers enabling this features such as [Redis](http://redis.io) also try not to implement this feature yourself as there are a lot of pitfalls and for details you can check the following links

- http://redis.io/topics/persistence
- http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html